Fluid Simulation is in the wrong place and positioning
so i was building a simple fluid simulation, I got everything set up like I usually would, and then I hit bake. my simulation and geometry for the Fluid domain are upside down. Any help and/or information with how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Here are some SS's.





If I look at your capture, it appears to look fine in terms of the particle simulation portion -- slow (blue-ish) water at the topd, then spreading and turning to green (higher velocity) and yellow at the bottom where it splashes outward.  You may want to upload and share your file via blend-exchange

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iVbHjHoHwL41s709cJa7aAl-cGoSXURQ?usp=sharing

My clue:  I noticed that the "Voxel size indicator" (the little orange square at one corner of your Domain object) is in the upper right instead of lower left corner. This was somehow inverting gravity.
I applied all transforms to the domain object:

and all is healed in simulation land:

solution file: 
